# WPF: How to crop/clip a Drawing or a DrawingImage?

Tags: wpf, image, drawing

I have a function receiving a Drawing that I need to partially expose as a DrawingImage (i.e.: its position and size will be reduced/changed to fit in a target area).

How can I crop/clip a region of the original Drawing?
Or maybe it is easier to do that after the transformation to DrawingImage (how clip that DrawingImage)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to encapsulate the original Drawing in a DrawingGroup and then apply a clipping geometry...

```
public DrawingGroup MyClippingFunc(Drawing OriginalDrawing, Rect ClippingArea)
{
    var Group = new DrawingGroup();
    Group.Children.Add(OriginalDrawing);
    Group.ClipGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(ClippingArea);

    return Group;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is another way to do it, using the InkCanvas StrokeCollection class as an example.

```
using (DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingGroup.Open())
                {
                    drawingContext.PushClip(new RectangleGeometry(yourRectangleObject));
                    Strokes.Draw(drawingContext);
                    drawingContext.Pop();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused on what you are asking but maybe my answer to this similar question will help?

[How can I use a PathGeometry as a mask for a BitmapSource (or any image data)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610114/how-can-i-use-a-pathgeometry-as-a-mask-for-a-bitmapsource-or-any-image-data/2615049#2615049)

Comment: Sorry, i mean DrawingImage instead of Image.

Comment: Right, but I still don't understand how you need to use it. A DrawingImage can be set as the Source of an Image control. In this case, my linked solution of setting the image.clip property I think will get what you want?

Comment: I need to do that in a library function, where is not known yet where/how the result will be used (e.g. that Image control you propose).